# Uploadify - file select dialog goes behind the popup window

Tags: file-upload, uploadify

I am using uploadify in a child window. that is if i click on a image it will open a new window using javascript.. inside the child popup window, i am having the uploadify.

everything works fine. but when clicking Browser Files flash button, the file select dialog goes behind the child window. anybody please help to focus the file select dialog to the current popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link so we can test this? It seems like a problem on how your computer is rendering dialogs.

I believe the browser can't control whether the dialog will be created on top of all windows or behind all windows.

Comment: thanks for answering.. at present i am working locally..so i can't give u the link..i restored all settings in IE9 and it works now..